# Inversion avec le même sujet mais divers verbes ?

Tags: grammaire, questions, interrogative

Est-il juste d'appliquer l'inversion à une question qui possède un sujet mais maints verbes ?

> G1. Est-ce que {sujet} {verbe 1} ... {verbe 2} ... et {verbe n} ... ?

La phrase 1, équivaut-elle à:

> G2. {Verbe 1}-(t)-{sujet} ... {Verbe 2}-(t)-{sujet} ... et {Verbe n}-(t)-{sujet} ... ^?

En outre, comment peut-on écourter la phrase G2 (et E2) encore plus? Par exemple:

E1. Pourquoi est-ce que tu t'empoignes à, te livres à, et scotches ce motif ?

E2. Pourquoi t'empoignes-tu à, te livres-tu à, et scotches-tu ce motif?

Comment: Excepté le sens qui me parait douteux, grammaticalement ça ne me choque pas. Lorsqu'il y a des prépositions intercalées ce n'est pas très fluide, mais ce n'est qu'une question d'esthétique.

Answer (score 1):

> E2. Pourquoi t'empoignes-tu, te livres-tu, et te scotches-tu sur ce motif?

(native's response) : Avec cette manière de parler, c'est une question insistante.

Answer (score 0):

S'il y a équivalence grammaticale, il n'y a pas équivalence d'emploi, car ils n'ont pas du tout d'équivalence rythmique. C'est aussi une question d'oreille et de sonorité amenant un souffle différent lors de la prononciation.

- G1 : s'emploiera facilement dans des alexandrins comme ceux de Victor Hugo, il s'accordera aussi avec les vers de dix pieds du *Roman de renard*, ou dans des phrases à périodes utilisées dans les démonstrations littéraires ou philosophiques.
- G2 : utilise la *[syncope](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_%28musique%29)* que l'on retrouve dans le jazz, certaines recherches d'expressions contemporaines, mais aussi dans des textes visant à alerter ou à mettre en valeur certaines informations.

Pour *faire court*, on peut utiliser les méthodes de *[contraction de texte](http://www.prepa-hec.org/ressources/culture-generale/methode-contraction-texte/methode-contraction-texte/)*.
Les textes de loi sont des modèles très aboutis.

On peut aussi utiliser l'expression poétique (avec ou sans rimes), utiliser l'infinitif :

> S'empoigner à, se livrer à,
> ... et scotcher ce motif, ... pourquoi ?

On emploie les points de suspension, non pas pour permettre à l'imagination du lecteur un ajout de mots ou d'idées, mais pour donner une pause, pour permettre une lecture cohérente dans un univers déstructuré.
Le maître étant *[Louis-Ferdinand Céline](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Ferdinand_C%C3%A9line)*, dont *Voyage au bout de la nuit* ou *Mort à crédit* ont déclenché une nouvelle façon d'écrire pour les auteurs du siècle dernier.